# Laravel doesn't update changes

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to build a website using Laravel with React, including the breeze starter kit.

The build works fine and running well, but every time I change anything in any of the pages it doesn't show; it just shows the starter website that came with Laravel, even if I delete the file it still get that page!

I've tried to delete caches, even tried

- php artisan view:clear
- I've tried to delete the cache files
- delete vendor and *composer.lock* and then do composer update
- tried to clear cache and storage. Even a new web browser
- every solution I found in Stack Overflow for the same problem (didn't work)
- edit *app.blade.php*. It did show changes, but not showing changes on jsx pages even though the pages are running from jsx itself.

I'm running the build locally using a 8000 port number. Also, there isn't another build running. I did test that if I stopped the build, it doesn't show anything, so there isn't another build running on top of that one.

Comment: did you run `npm run dev` or `npm run build`?

Comment: If you run `npm run build` it will compile all the assets and created them somewhere in `public/build` assuming you did not change any settings.

Comment: Run this command on every deployment (production, test server, etc)

Comment: If you run `npm run dev` it will create a `hot reload` state where if you save your asset changes, it will upload on your browser ( for local testing )

Comment: This is all me assuming the changes you are talking about are css/js type changes.

Comment: Are you even running the web server?

Comment: running `npm run build` fixes the problem also running  `npm run dev` made hot reload thanks @Mr.Kenneth

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem by:

- run `npm run build` to apply the changes for deployment
- run `npm run dev` to make hot reload whenever I made changes

Comment: If you are in development (localhost) and using `npm run dev`, make sure you delete the old `public/build` so that your app wont be confused which assets to load.